# Integrals: Partial Fractions

Tags: calculus, integration

$$ \int \frac{x^2-x+12}{x^3+3x} $$

I factored the denominator to get $ x(x^2+3) $. I then seperated the x and the $x^2+3$ into the partials $\frac{A}{x}$ and $\frac{Bx+C}{x^2+3}$.

After combining the two, I came up with $$ \frac{A(x^2+3)+ x(Bx+C)}{x(x^2+3)}$$

This is where I'm stuck. I'm assuming that A would equal 1 because it is where $x^2$ is in the original problem. The same would go for b equaling -1 and $C = 12$. I'm not so sure though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $x^2-x+12=12$ when $x=0$.

Note also that $A(x^2+3)+x(Bx+C)=3A$ when $x=0$. Thus $A=\frac{12}{3}=4$.

The coefficient of $x^2$ in $x^2-x+12$ is $1$. In  $A(x^2+3)+x(Bx+C)$ it is $A+B$. Since $A=4$, we have $B=-3$.

We leave finding $C$ to you.

Comment: Why did you choose x as zero?

Comment: It is a standard trick. For a simpler example, suppose we want $\frac{3x+5}{(x-2)(x+4)}=\frac{A}{x-2}+\frac{B}{x+4}$. So we want $3x+5=A(x+4)+B(x-2)$. Set $x=2$. That tells us $A$. Set $x=-4$. That tells us $B$.

Comment: The technique described by Claude Leibovici also works well. But some tricks can simplify life quite a bit.

Answer (score 1):

You are almots done. As you wrote $$ \frac{x^2-x+12}{x^3+3x}=\frac{A}{x}+\frac{Bx+C}{x^2+3}$$ then $${x^2-x+12}=A(x^2+3)+(Bx+C)x$$Expand the rhs, so $${x^2-x+12}=(A+B)x^2+Cx+3A$$ Identify the coefficients for a given power of $x$; so $$A+B=1$$ $$C=-1$$ $$3A=12$$ So, $A=4$, $B=-3$,$C=-1$